# c++ retrieving object from tree

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-search-tree

I am working on a project in which I have an account class that stores balances for different funds. Each account object has 10 funds in which they start at 0 and transactions such as deposit, withdraw, and tranfer can be made. I need to store these accounts in a binary search tree as they are added and I am having issues with my retrieve function. The code is the following:

```
bool Retrieve(const int & acctNum, Account* acctPtr)
{
    if (Search(root, acctPtr, acctNum))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Search(Node* temp, Account* acctPtr, int acctNum)
{
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (temp->pAcct->getAcct() == acctNum)
    {
        acctPtr = temp->pAcct;
        return true;
    }
    else if (acctNum <= temp->pAcct->getAcct())
    {
        return Search(temp->left, acctPtr, acctNum);
    }
    else
    {
        return Search(temp->right, acctPtr, acctNum);
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is when I deposit into the account and then later retrieve and try to withdraw, it is not giving me the same account. Rather, it just tries to withdraw from an account with all 0 balances. My intention is for the acctPtr to point to the correct account to do the transfer/withdraw/deposit too. Here is how I am calling the retrieve from a different class that is used for completing the transactions:

```
    if (transType == "D")
    {
        iss >> acctNum >> amt;
        fund = parseCommand(acctNum);
        acctNum = acctNum.substr(0, acctNum.length() - 1);

        Account * d = new Account("name", stoi(acctNum));
        if (bST->Retrieve(stoi(acctNum), d))
        {
            d->deposit(fund, amt);
            cout << d->getFundBalance(fund) << endl; //for checking, will remove
        }
    }
    else if (transType == "W")
    {
        iss >> acctNum >> amt;
        fund = parseCommand(acctNum);
        acctNum = acctNum.substr(0, acctNum.length() - 1);

        Account * wD = new Account("name", stoi(acctNum));
        if (bST->Retrieve(stoi(acctNum), wD))
        {
            wD->withdraw(fund, amt);
            cout << wD->getFundBalance(fund) << endl; //for checking, will remove
        }
    }
```

The if statements above are just checking the type of transaction at the given time.

Comment: What do you think this line does?  `acctPtr = temp->pAcct;`  (hint:  what is acctPtr?)

Comment: aside:  you should read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thank you for the link to the reading, it will be helpful for future projects. My intention with this line is to set the pointer of the Account object to be a pointer to the specific object found in the search. This way when I make a transaction, it modifies the retrieved value.

Comment: try putting a breakpoint there; check it's value ... then go past the return, and then check its value again

Comment: I was able to solve it using the solution given. Thank you for your help, I am still learning the concept of pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Search function, you use the argument acctPtr as an output (you assigned a new value to it).

But your pointer is not an output argument.

You should use Account** or Account*&.

And you will have to use the Retrieve method like this :

```
Account* d = NULL;
if(bST->Retrieve(stoi(acctNum),&d /* or just d if Account*& */))
{ ... }
```

If you use the Account** version, don't forget to assign the pointer with

```
*acctPtr = temp->pAcct;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this solved my problem. I am still new to pointers so I appreciate the clarification!